# Define an unknown function with an arbitrary number of variables

Tags: function-construction

I'm working with unknown functions, for example I have

```
f = g[Subscript[x,1],Subscript[x,2],Subscript[x,3]]
```

, where `g` haven't been defined previously, therefore `f` is an unknown function depending in 3 variables. How can I, given `d`, define `f` as

```
f = g[Subscript[x,1],...,Subscript[x,d]]
```

without typing it manually?

Comment: try `ClearAll[f,g]; f = g[##] &;` (see [SlotSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) and [howto/WorkWithPureFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html) in the docs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you want to do this (beware `Subscript`), but:

```
d = 5;
f = Apply[g, Table[Subscript[x, n], {n, 1, d}]];
f
(* g[Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]] *)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the question.